# How to retrieve entries from the table by the set of keys the quickest way?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I am working with the database using qt. One of the things i need is to retrieve some part of the table with some keyset as the input data. This is the code i use:

```
bool getData(const QList<int> &idlist, QVector<DataStruct> &result)
{
    result.resize(idlist.size());
    QSqlDatabase &dbase = QSqlDatabase::database(conname); //conname is the QString holding the name of a connection
    if (!dbase.transaction())
        return false;
    QString queryString(
            "SELECT <column list> "
            "FROM MyTableAS k "
            "JOIN JoinedTable AS d ON k.foreign_key=d.primary_key "
            "WHERE k.key=:key");
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase::database(conname));
    if(!query->prepare(queryString))
    {
        delete query;
        dbase.rollback();
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < idlist.size(); i++)
    {
        query->bindValue(":key",idlist[i]);
        if (!query->exec())
        {
            delete query;
            dbase.rollback();
            return false;
        }
        DataStruct &k = result[i];
        memset(&k,0,sizeof(DataStruct));
        if(query->next())
        {
            // fields of structure are mapped to query results
        }
        //result.append(k);
    }
    dbase.commit();
    delete query;
    return true;
}
```

I was wondering, how to speed the retrieval up. Should i change the query - if so, how? Should i be using transactions here? Should i change the way i work with database to something else?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correct, but you might want to do a select query with IN clause and then Iterate over the results.

Comment: What table are the SELECT columns from?

Comment: All the columns from MyTable and JoinedTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query seems to be well-written (well, an explicit column list is better than using `*`, but that has a minimal effect on performance).

You can speed up the query by putting an index on `MyTable(key)`.  You should already have an index on the primary key, if it is declared as such.

Comment: I am using explicit column list; i didn't list it for simplicity's sake.